# Replace Double Double Quotes

Tags: vb.net

I need to replace double double quotes but not replace fields with empty values.

Question: How can I replace double double quotes and not replace empty columns?

---

Original Line

""COTTAGE"","PENNINGTON, NJ","","123456789"

Expected outcome

"COTTAGE","PENNINGTON, NJ","","123456789"

---

I have created a class that will do the trick, but it replaces all double double quotes, including the empty field:

---

My code outcome

"COTTAGE","PENNINGTON, NJ",","123456789"

as you can see my code fixes COTTAGE, but kills the empty column after ,NJ to have a single double quote.

---

> Public Class FixFileErrors
>
> ```
> Public Shared Sub RemoveDoubleDoubleQuotes(ByVal FilePathandName As String)
>
>     Dim OriginalFile, RevisedFile, LineofText As String
>
>     OriginalFile = FilePathandName
>     RevisedFile = Replace(OriginalFile, ".txt", "revised.txt")
>
>
>     Dim srFileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
>     srFileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(OriginalFile)
>     'Dim srFileWritter As System.IO.StreamWriter
>     Dim srFileWritter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(RevisedFile)
>
>
>     Do Until srFileReader.EndOfStream
>         LineofText = srFileReader.ReadLine
>         LineofText = ReplaceDoubleDoubleQuotes(LineofText)
>         srFileWritter.WriteLine(LineofText)
>         LineofText = Nothing
>     Loop
>
> End Sub
>
> Public Shared Function ReplaceDoubleDoubleQuotes(ByVal Line As String) As String
>     Dim NewLine As String
>
>
>     Dim strFindText As String = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
>     Dim strReplaceText As String = Chr(34)
>
>     NewLine = Replace(Line, strFindText, strReplaceText)
>
>
>     Return NewLine
>
> End Function
> ```
>
> End Class

Comment: first get the empty string and replace it with some odd string say, "!~!%$@%$@%$%", and after removing the double quote, revert it back. Will this do?

Comment: look at using the `String.Replace` method [MSDN VB.NET String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceDoubleDoubleQuotes(ByVal Line As String) As String
    Dim NewLine As String

    Dim doubleDoubleQuotes As String = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    Dim doubleQuote As String = Chr(34)

    'Your original replacement
    NewLine = Replace(Line, doubleDoubleQuotes, doubleQuote)

    'Replacement to fix double-quotes between commas
    NewLine = Replace(NewLine, "," & doubleQuote & ",", "," & doubleDoubleQuotes & ",")

    Return NewLine

End Function
```